# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear el carácter @ en un campo de un formulario?

Tags: html, formularios

Estoy recibiendo montañas de spam desde mi formulario de mensajes, todos tienen en común que repiten la dirección de email como "nombre y apellido"

¿Cómo puedo bloquear el carácter @ en el campo?

Esta es la linea en mi formulario html:

```html
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" class="campo-form" required style="width: 410px">
```

Comment: Lo más probable es que no te sirva de nada hacer una validación desde el frontend (HTML / JS). Ese chequeo deberías hacerlo desde el backend. Qué lenguaje estás utilizando?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Luego entra a [edit] tu pregunta: 1. incluye el código que usas en el servidor para recibir y tratar los datos enviados por el formulario. 2. Especifica los lenguajes que usas. 3. Muestra cómo guardas la información, posiblemente seas susceptible a ataques que vulneran la seguridad de tu sitio. Como te indicó @azeós **las validaciones de seguridad del lado del cliente son inútiles** (no puedo explicar la razón en este espacio)

Comment: Gracias Azeós y Quevedo, en realidad soy diseñador gráfico, no web y conozco muy poco sobre el tema, de hecho mis páginas están hechas con Expression web :-)
Los formularios y ediciones de mis páginas está hechas copiando códigos que encuentro en internet, me sorprende que funcionen a pesar de mi ignorancia. 
www.goldpack.com.ar
Gracias por sus respuestas, de acuerdo a lo que me dicen,voy a probar con la respuesta de Rudy y si no funciona... aguantaré el spam. Abrazo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes validarlo con un pattern, quedando algo asi:

```html
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" pattern="[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,5}" class="campo-form" style="width:410px" required/>
```

Lo que agregarás a tu input será esto:

`pattern="[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,25}"`

Estas líneas te dicen que se aceptan caracteres minúsculos y mayúsculos de la aA-zZ, con un mínimo de un carácter y un máximo de veinticinco. Esos datos tu puedes modificarlos a tu antojo. Como acá no hay caracteres especiales y tampoco está la @ pues no la pedirá la validación del pattern.

Cabe mencionar que también existen mas opciones de validación, pero esta es una de las mas sencillas.

Espero te sirva, pero te recomiendo que busques otras mejores formas de validación.

Comment: Está muy bien, pero no le va a servir de nada si recibe spam, que lo más probable es que NO venga del formulario HTML, [tal cual comentó azeós](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398576/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-bloquear-el-car%c3%a1cter-en-el-campo-de-apellido-y-nombre-de-un-form#comment712781_398576)

Comment: La verdad hay mucha razón en todo. Al menos, temporalmente puede usar el pattern por mientras busca mejores formas de validación según mi recomendación. Esperemos que publique el código para poder verlo y encontrar que causa el spam.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Rudy y Pollo; tengo captcha, que disminuyó el ritmo, pero algunos mensajes siguen llegando. Voy a probar con la linea que me envías, me parece muy útil . También sospecho que no usan el formulario, pero no cuesta nada probar. 
Gracias de nuevo por la respuesta y los voy a mantener al tanto.
Cordiales saludos.

Comment: Dale... Es un placer... Estamos a la orden... Saludos.

Comment: Excelente Rudy, lo agregué, funciona perfecto, se terminó el spam (al menos por ahora).
Muchas gracias y un abrazo!
www.goldpack.com.ar